# Camel CXFRS response

Tags: apache-camel

camel-fuse 2.8

I have a camel jaxrs server which accepts requests then kicks-off 2 Camel routes.

The first route, consumes requests from cxfrs endpoint/bean and ships them to jms queue *inbox*.

The second route, consumes requests from jms queue *inbox* for business logic processing, then ships the **results** to jms queue *outbox*.

My question is related to http response and sending the **results** to jaxrs server consumer.

Is it possible to send an http response back to http client from first route with **results** from second route? (synchronously)

```
        from("cxfrs:bean:personLookupEndpoint")   <-- http client waits for response...
            .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
            .process(new RequestProcessor())
            .to(inbox);


        from(inbox)
            .unmarshal(jaxb)
            .process(new QueryServiceProcessor())
            .to("bean:lookupService?method=processQuery(${body})")
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)
            .to(outbox);  <-- need to send results to font-end consumer synchronously ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to do it using queues? I think that it would be better to use direct: routes instead.

There is a possibility to use the InOut exchange pattern for a JMS endpoint, but it has some limitations: http://fusesource.com/docs/router/2.2/transactions/JMS-Synchronous.html